# Как в БД хранить прикрепленные (документы, видео, фото) к посту?

Tags: php, mysql

Как в БД хранить прикрепленные (документы, видео, фото) к посту?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего хранить ссылку на ресурсы.

Comment: как должна быть организована БД. У меня сейчас таблица posts в ней

     id_post | author | text

Comment: Лучше всего создать дополнительную таблицу, в которой будут хранится вложения. Например:

id | id_post | src | title | type

id_post - ID поста, src - относительный путь к файлу на сервере, title - Название документа, type - тип. Далее, я думаю, Вы сами решите, что нужно, а что нет.